# Как переключиться на следующий элемент массива в цикле for python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, массивы, for

Например, чтобы вывести 2 элемента внутри одного блока:

```
arr = ['one','two','three','four'];

for x in arr:
    .........
    print()...
```

На выходе:

```
 one, two
 three, four
```

Comment: `for x in (arr[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(arr), 2)):`.

Answer (score 2):

```
for i in range(0, len(arr), 2):
    if i < len(arr) - 1:
        print(arr[i], arr[i + 1])
    else
        print(arr[i])
```

При использовании print на одной строке - посмотреть его параметр end

Comment: да просто ``print(arr[i], arr[i + 1])``

Comment: Будет ошибка, если в списке нечетное количество элементов.

Answer (score 2):

Проверял на более массивных данных:

```
arr = list(range(1,20))

for x, y in zip(arr[::2], arr[1::2]):
  print(x, y)
else: # на случай нечётного количества элементов
  if len(arr)%2 == 1:
    print(arr[-1])
```

Альтернативное решение с упаковщиком из модуля `itertools`:

```py
from itertools import zip_longest as izip
arr = list(range(1,20))

for x, y in izip(arr[::2], arr[1::2], fillvalue=''):
  print(x, y)
```

Результат:

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
7 8
9 10
11 12
13 14
15 16
17 18
19
```

О срезах можно почитать [тут](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/indeksy-i-srezy.html).
О том, как работает функция `zip`, можно почитать [тут](https://younglinux.info/python/feature/zip).

Answer (score 1):

Можно как-то так

```
for count, x in enumerate(arr, start=1):
    end_string = ', ' if count % 2 else '\n'
    print(x, end=end_string)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools, collections, warnings


def chunks_from1(size, val):
    if not isinstance(val, collections.Iterator): val = iter(val)
    while True:
        chunk = list(itertools.islice(val, size))
        if chunk: yield chunk
        else: break


def chunks_from2(size, val):
    if not isinstance(val, collections.Iterator): val = iter(val)
    while True:
        chunk = []
        for _ in range(size):
            try: chunk.append(next(val))
            except StopIteration:
                if chunk: yield chunk
                return
        yield chunk


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)  # C:/SCR/NEW_STAND/ii.py:12: DeprecationWarning: Using or importing the ABCs from 'collections' instead of from 'collections.abc' is deprecated since Python 3.3, and in 3.9 it will stop working
    for b in chunks_from1(2, range(11)):
        print(b)
    # print()
    # for b in chunks_from2(2, list(range(11)):
    #     print(b)
```

-

```
[0, 1]
[2, 3]
[4, 5]
[6, 7]
[8, 9]
[10]
```